# Points to Path does not work

Tags: qgis, data-collection, points-to-line

I have a data set from a collard animal separated by days, I want to create an individual line from each day of data to know how the animal has moved in the forest. When I use the plugin points2path it only creates lots of line but I can not differentiate each day, I am using wrong the plugin? Does any body know a better way to do it?

Comment: What software are you using? And could you please provide the format of your data?

Comment: I am working with Qgis, my data are separeted in day, hour and the coords are in UTM